# Как сделать чтобы кноgки были посередине рамки?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, flexbox

Как мне сделать кнопку посередине (высота) в рамке?
[image: Тут показано что кнопки не по середине]

```css
.topnav {
  background-size: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.frame {
  border: 2px solid white;
  padding: 10px;
}

.wrap {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.button {
  margin-left: 10px;
  min-width: 250px;
  min-height: 40px;
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  font-size: 22px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1.3px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #313133;
  background: #4FD1C5;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(129, 230, 217, 1) 0%, rgba(79, 209, 197, 1) 100%);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 1000px;
  box-shadow: 12px 12px 24px rgba(79, 209, 197, .64);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
}

button::before {
  content: '';
  border-radius: 1000px;
  min-width: calc(300px + 12px);
  min-height: calc(60px + 12px);
  border: 6px solid #00FFCB;
  box-shadow: 0 0 60px rgba(0, 255, 203, .64);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.button:hover,
.button:focus {
  color: #313133;
  transform: translateY(-6px);
}

button:hover::before,
button:focus::before {
  opacity: 1;
}

button:hover::after,
button:focus::after {
  animation: none;
  display: none;
}

@keyframes ring {
  0% {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="frame">
  <div class="topnav">
    <button class="button">Главная</button>
    <button class="button">Магазин</button>
    <button class="button">О нас</button>
    <button class="button">Калькулятор</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавил стили классу `.topnav`

```css
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
```

```css
.topnav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-size: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.frame {
  border: 2px solid white;
  padding: 10px;
}

.wrap {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.button {
  margin-left: 10px;
  min-width: 250px;
  min-height: 40px;
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  font-size: 22px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1.3px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #313133;
  background: #4FD1C5;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(129, 230, 217, 1) 0%, rgba(79, 209, 197, 1) 100%);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 1000px;
  box-shadow: 12px 12px 24px rgba(79, 209, 197, .64);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
}

button::before {
  content: '';
  border-radius: 1000px;
  min-width: calc(300px + 12px);
  min-height: calc(60px + 12px);
  border: 6px solid #00FFCB;
  box-shadow: 0 0 60px rgba(0, 255, 203, .64);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.button:hover,
.button:focus {
  color: #313133;
  transform: translateY(-6px);
}

button:hover::before,
button:focus::before {
  opacity: 1;
}

button:hover::after,
button:focus::after {
  animation: none;
  display: none;
}

@keyframes ring {
  0% {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="frame">
  <div class="topnav">
    <button class="button">Главная</button>
    <button class="button">Магазин</button>
    <button class="button">О нас</button>
    <button class="button">Калькулятор</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Можно будет как то обойти display или его flex? дело в том что у меня картинка, которая должна быть справа а из за flex она становится в середину и ее ничем не передвинуть

Comment: Если честно, я не совсем понял, что вы имели ввиду. Сверстать то, как угодно можно, но чтоб не гадать, желательно понимать, как должен выглядеть конечный вариант. Вы можете новый вопрос задать и там уже подробно, желательно с примером, объяснить, как именно вы хотите сделать.